# Nebular timepicker input shows 'date' instead of 'time' when the time is removed

Tags: html, angular, typescript, timepicker, nebular

There is a strange thing happening with nebular time picker. Every time I try to remove the 'time' from the nebular time picker input, it shows date instead.

The code I have added in my files-

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    NbTimepickerModule.forRoot({
      localization: {
        hoursText: 'Hr',
        minutesText: 'Min',
        secondsText: 'Sec',
        ampmText: 'Am/Pm',
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [CanDeactivateGuard],
  exports: [TranslateModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

.html

```
<input
   class="mt-2 mb-1"
   nbInput fullWidth
   type="text"
   placeholder="HH:MM"
   formControlName="examTimeFb"
   required
   [status]="(myForm.controls['examTimeFb'].dirty ||
   myForm.controls['examTimeFb'].touched) ?
   (myForm.controls['examTimeFb'].invalid ?
   'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'"
   [nbTimepicker]="timepicker"/>
<nb-timepicker #timepicker twelveHoursFormat></nb-timepicker>
```

.ts

```
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    examTimeFb: [this.examTime ? this.examTime : '', Validators.required],
});
```

This is how the time looks when it is selected from the nebular input by pressing on the 'ok' button available.

[image]

But when this time is backspaced and removed, it changes to-

[image: From] -->
[image: To]

I have even tried to change the formcontrol value to a blank string, null using -

```
(blur)="dateManage()"
```

and tried to implement with [(ngModel)], the timepicker behaves the same way in all cases.
What am I doing wrong? Or what can be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? We are also encountering this issue.